# Igraph runs in Python console but not from script

Tags: python, igraph

I've installed igraph on Python 3.7.2 using the wheel at https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-igraph and 'pip install python-igraph'. I attempted to create a simple graph with:

```
import igraph
g = igraph.Graph()
```

This works when I run it in the console (IDLE) but when I write it in a script and execute it, the second command gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path\igraph.py", line 1, in <module>
    import igraph
  File "path\igraph.py", line 3, in <module>
    g = igraph.Graph()
AttributeError: module 'igraph' has no attribute 'Graph'
```

Previously I wrongly used 'pip install igraph" but later uninstalled it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you named your executable file igraph.py, so there is a name conflict. Just rename the file